# 53MB .zip file fails to upload to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a ~53MB .zip file to my S3 bucket but it fails every time (gets to about 50%-60% progress then fails).

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Error: [image]

Comment: In my experience, keep trying and it'll work eventually. I appreciate that this doesn't actually answer the question, which is why it's a comment. In the intended spirit of comments, to request improvements and clarifications, I'll ask you to [edit] your question to include the precise error message you see.

Answer (score 3):

Try using aws-cli. I have had many issues using the S3 UI, especially for deleting very large buckets.

```
$ aws s3 cp /path/to/myfile.zip s3://bucketname/path/
```